# Why wont my CSS syntax register?

Tags: notepad++

I was coding the other day when my computer started to close every tab that was open including notepad++, I restarted my computer and when I tried to save my code it says the document was open somewhere else. I deleted all my code and saved it to a notepad, then I went back to notepad++ and pasted my code into it. Now my css syntax is not registering when I try to make changes.

Comment: Is there a filetype set correctly for syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

select:

```
language -> C -> CSS
```